# intellij - search options

Tags: intellij-idea

(using intellij 10)
Suddenly when i locate my mouse over a data member and press alt-f7 it gives me the results of the different usages without separating them to different categories (value read, value write, etc... )
what did I clicked wrong?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the *Usages of* pop-up? I am not quite sure what is your problem, but look at header of this window, on the left side you have a set of icons:

- Show read access
- Show write access
- Show import statements...

Also on the top-right corner of this window there is a tool icon, which you can use to customize the view even further.